# Perl parsing through a file based on conditions

Tags: regex, perl, if-statement, data-structures

I have a very large log file which is updated periodically. It is as follows:

```
commands: (List of files to be copied)
Exit time: Fri May 10 05:33:00 2013
Exit status: 2

commands: (List of files to be copied)
Exit Time: Fri May 20 05:34:00 2013
Exit status: 2

commands: (List of files to be copied)
Exit Time: Fri May 30 05:50:00 2013
Exit Status: 1
```

I have following code which creates a hash based on Exit Status

```
while ($line = <FH>) {
        if ($line =~ /Exit time/) {
        ($exittime, $exittimeval) = split(': ',$line);
         $stat{$qbsid} = {
            time     => $exittimeval
            };
}
```

I now need to create a timestamp based on localtime such that the script does not compare the log file for the time after the timestamp (localtime). I have the code to compare the time as follows

```
 $date1 = "$hr1:$min1:$sec1, $moy1/$dt1/$yr1";
 $date2 = "$hr2:$min2:$sec2, $moy2/$dt2/$yr2";
 sub to_comparable {
    my ($date) = @_;
    my ($H,$M,$S,$d,$m,$Y) = $date =~ m{^(\d+):(\d+):(\d+), (\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\z}
      or die;
    return "$Y$m$d$H$M$S";
}

if (to_comparable($date2) > to_comparable($date1)) {
print "right\n";
} else {
        print "wrong \n";
}
```

Here $hr1,$min1,$sec1,$moy1,$dt1 and $yr1 are local time variables while $hr2,$min2,$sec2, $moy2,$dt2 and $yr2 are values obtained from hash.

Preferably while running for the first time it should compare the whole file and a timestamp is created. Afterwards, the above idea starts.

Please correct me if anything is wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Time-Piece-1.22/Piece.pm), which was first released with perl v5.9.5.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

{
    my $end_date = '2013-05-30';

    local $/ = '';
    while (<DATA>) {
        if (/^Exit Time: (.+)/m) {
            my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%c");
            print $date->ymd, "\n" if $date->ymd lt $end_date;
        }
    }   
}

__DATA__
commands: (List of files to be copied)
Exit Time: Fri May 10 05:33:00 2013
Exit status: 2

commands: (List of files to be copied)
Exit Time: Fri May 20 05:34:00 2013
Exit status: 2

commands: (List of files to be copied)
Exit Time: Fri May 30 05:50:00 2013
Exit Status: 1
```

Output:

```
2013-05-10
2013-05-20
```

Comment: Any alternative to Time::Piece module..If I can go with normal comparision like year,month,date,hour,minute,second..Just a suggestion..Thank you

Comment: @deep Its available on perl 10 or newer. Why wouldn't you want to use it? Yes, you could code it up by hand if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be forming a 20-digit number (assuming years are 4-digit and the rest are always exactly 2-digit).  That's a big number, but it seems fine on my 64-bit UNIX OS; I don't know about yours.  Anyway, with a fixed-length string, you could do a string comparison ("ge" instead of ">") if a number that big is an issue.

If any of the inputs (e.g. $moy1) could be a single digit, then your comparison function will not work since the October 1st (2013101) would be before September 30th (2013930).  You could require a fixed number of digits using:

```
my ($H,$M,$S,$d,$m,$Y) = $date =~ m{^(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d), (\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d\d\d)\z}
      or die;
```

I'm sure how $qbsid is set (from Exit Status or something else), but since your code isn't complete I assume you have something else to do that.

I'm also not sure how your original time strings (e.g. "Fri May 30 05:50:00 2013") get transformed into the "$hr1:$min1:$sec1, $moy1/$dt1/$yr1" format, but I assume you do that elsewhere as well.

Comment: @kjpres It is 16-bit number..So, it worked fine for the system..Thanks